# 2016 SSIS Package- Duplicate connections

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016, ssis-connection-manager

We have noticed the SSIS packages has created duplicate connections in the package , not sure when we open the solution the package was trying to connect to the server credentials and unavailable due to the passwords and had created a duplicate connection

Did anyone of you face this strange issue and found a solution for this.

Comment: An SSIS package cannot create a connection manager by its own.

Comment: Do you have a connection in your package and then one on the project level maybe?